# Neo4j Object Graph Mapping how to implement relationships

Tags: php, sql, orm, neo4j

I am working on a Object Graph Mapper (OGM) for Neo4j. It helps me understand the workflow of Neo4j better. I am encountering one big problem on the implementation of relations of an object.

The way I approached the OGM itself was to create "models" based on the indexes. So the index "users" correspond to class "User". All the properties work as intended etc. When it comes to relationships, I tried to implement it similar to ORM relationships. However, one big difference between SQL and Graph Databases is that, graphs do not have static tables; and relationship endpoints "types" can change from node to node. For example, if I have a "likes" relationship, it can go to node class "Book", "Movie". I cannot just create a relationship in the same way I create SQL: (relationshipName, relationshipType, fkID, modelName).

How should I approach this problem? What will be a better design option? Should I automatically find the class based on the index of the node? Should I omit the object that do not have the same index?

The way I am implementing it right now is (relationshipName, relationshipType, relationshipDirection, modelName). Example of usage would be ("likedBy", "likes", "in", "User"), ("likes", "likes", "out", "Thing").

Answer (score 1):

When in comes to building an OGM, which i am also working on. I felt that their is atleast two types of constraints that needs to be taken care of.

First kind of constraint is the one you described, lets call it Property Schema. That sets the schema for the properties on an element (i.e.. a node or a relationship). Using this you can index on a specific property, give labels to nodes, impose uniqueness constraint based on a particular property and can impose the soft constraints on the data elements that you put. like a Date property should be between `1-31`. Neo4j currently doesn't support any constraint other than the uniqueness constraint. So these has to be imposed at the OGM level itself.

Another kind of constraint that is needed is a Structural Schema. This will impose a set of structural constraints on an element (i.e.. a node or a relationship). These sets of constraints will make sure that a element is following all the conditions when it gets connected to its neighborhood elements. In these set of constraints you can define constraints on relationships like: A relationship of type `LIKES` can connect a node with label `USER` to nodes with label `BOOK or MUSIC or (FOOD and DRINK)`. Similarly you can put constraints on a node like: A node with label `USER` is required to be connected to atleast one another node with label `USER` using an outgoing relationship of type `Friend`.

You can express these kind of constraints using the cypher language `MATCH` patterns. I am currently working on the first phase of this OGM, which i am developing for node.js. This is my current understanding about how i am going to approach the problem. hope it helps.